# Retrieving data from PostgreSQL database using SharpLite

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

The problem is that my MVC app is connecting well to my database but when I query it it doesn't return anything(`var model` is `empty`) and I don't know what's the problem.I'm using `SharpLite` template so this already has automappings implemented and is connecting to my database using `NHibernate`, I already implemented the `User` entity in `MyProject.Domain`.
Here is the code in my `User Controller`:

```
private readonly IRepository<User> _repository; 
public UserController(IRepository<User> repository)
{
    _repository = repository;
}
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = _repository.GetAll();
    return View(model);
}
```

And this is the code from `NHibernate initializer`:

```
public static Configuration Initialize() 
{
    var configuration = new Configuration();

    configuration
         .Proxy(p => p.ProxyFactoryFactory<DefaultProxyFactoryFactory>())
          .DataBaseIntegration(db => {
             db.ConnectionStringName = "MyProjectConnectionString";
             db.Dialect<PostgreSQL82Dialect>();
          })
          .AddAssembly(typeof(ActionConfirmation<>).Assembly)
          .CurrentSessionContext<LazySessionContext>();

    var mapper = new ConventionModelMapper();
    mapper.WithConventions(configuration);

    return configuration;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to see the statements sent to the database, along with the results.
Try one of these methods:

- The easiest way I've found is using [NHibernate Profiler](http://nhprof.com/).  It's a pay product.
- Setup NHibernate to log SQL statements using [log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134565/how-to-configure-fluent-nhibernate-to-output-queries-to-trace-or-debug-instead-o/2135025#2135025).
- Custom output to Trace, Debug, or anywhere else you want using [an interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134565/how-to-configure-fluent-nhibernate-to-output-queries-to-trace-or-debug-instead-o/5437641#5437641)

I don't know enough about the problem to pinpoint the error currently.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your `User` entity inherits `Entity`