# See parameters of UPDATEs in Fluent NHibernate when outputting statements to Console

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

### Introduction

Following on from [How to configure Fluent NHibernate to output queries to Trace or Debug instead of Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134565/how-to-configure-fluent-nhibernate-to-output-queries-to-trace-or-debug-instead-o) the answer provided there nicely outputs information to the console with the exception that it outputs `?` instead of the actual values of parameters.

Additionally using `ShowSql()` does not output any `UPDATE` lines.

### Question

Is there a way to view the UPDATEs, parameters and all in the debug console?

### Details of implementations

#### Using Interceptor

From [How to configure Fluent NHibernate to output queries to Trace or Debug instead of Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134565/how-to-configure-fluent-nhibernate-to-output-queries-to-trace-or-debug-instead-o), I have implemented the following:

```
private class Interceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    public override SqlString OnPrepareStatement(SqlString sql)
    {
        var s = base.OnPrepareStatement(sql);
        Debug.WriteLine(s.ToString());
        return s;
    }
}
//... 

var factory = Fluently.Configure()
                      // ...
                      .ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetInterceptor(new Interceptor())
                      // ...
```

which results in outputs like

```
UPDATE [User] SET Email = ?, HashedPassword = ?, Name = ? WHERE Id = ?
```

#### Using ShowSql()

From [this blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/lszk/archive/2011/07/12/showing-a-sql-generated-by-nhibernate-on-the-vs-build-in.aspx) I have implemented the following

```
public class CustomDebugWriter : System.IO.TextWriter
{
    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(value);
        base.WriteLine(value);
    }
    public override void Write(string value)
    {
        Debug.Write(value);
        base.Write(value);
    }
    public override System.Text.Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return new UTF8Encoding(); }
    }
}
// ...

Console.SetOut(new CustomDebugWriter());
var dbConfig = MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(
    c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey(connectionStringKey));
dbConfig.ShowSql();
```

which doesn't output UPDATE statements at all.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with ISession's psuedo Unit Of Work and batching.

With Fluent-NHibernate you need to set the `AdoNetBatchSize` property:

```
dbConfig.AdoNetBatchSize(0);
dbConfig.ShowSql();
dbConfig.FormatSql();
```

Then after you do your update, you need to call `Flush()` to flush the "batch".

```
entity.Title = "test title";
Session.Update(entity);
Session.Flush();
```

It really depends on your architecture, where you call this, or if you are using your own Unit Of Work implementation. I only worry about the SQL output in my integration tests project so it's easy, I just call Flush on TearDown. Its probably not something you want to just throw in your App, it's usually best to just let NHibernate handle batch lifecycle and do its thing.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain how this will help?

Comment: @dav_i I ran into this issue years ago and answered too quickly, I forgot the AdoNetBatchSize step, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround rather than a true answer.

If you're creating a web-app, you can use the `Glimpse` and `NHibernate.Glimpse` Nuget packages to examine what database calls are being made.

This has the parameters shown.